# Clarification about Flexible Padding

Tags: css, responsive-design, padding

I'm reading Responsive Web Design by Ethan Marcotte to learn more about building responsive web pages. At one point in the book, he says:

> 1. When setting flexible margins on an element, your context is the width of the element’s container.
> 2. When setting flexible padding on an element, **your context is the width of the element itself**. Which makes sense, if you think about the box model: we’re describing the padding in relation to the width of the box itself.

Regarding flexible padding, I've found this to not be the case. The padding is based on the width of the element's containing element. Now I've found this book to be of high quality overall, so I'm confused as to whether there's something I'm not getting, or if the book just got it wrong.

I created a JSFiddle to get to demonstrate.

https://jsfiddle.net/u1fq7ttq/27/embedded/result/

HTML

```
<section>Content...</section>
<aside>Content...</aside>
```

CSS

```
body {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 3px solid red;
width: 520px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 2.0833333%; /* 20px / 960px */
padding: 0 3.125%; /* 30px / 960px */
float: left;
}

aside {
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 3px solid blue;    
width: 360px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 2.0833333%; /* 20px / 960px */
padding: 0 6.25%; /* 60px / 960px */
float: right;   
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure I'm following, but I think the missing piece is how `box-sizing` fits in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing If you remove `box-sizing: border-box;` does it behave the way are interpreting that it should from the article?

Comment: It behaves the same way. If you go into the developer tools, you will see that the padding on the section is 30px and 60px on the aside. The percentage is computed on the containing element's width (960px), not the element's width (500px and 360px respectively). According to the book, it should be relative to the element's width and not the containing element's width, but this isn't the case.